# Spring Social Facebook App Setup for getting the user information

Tags: mysql, facebook, spring-mvc, mybatis, spring-social

I am working on spring social login for facebook. I need to get the user information(firstname,lastname and email).Is there any specific app setup to get these details???

Answer (score 1):

The Spring Social Facebook project is an extension to Spring Social that enables integration with Facebook 
https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-facebook/